# How significant is the speed of native code for back end tasks?

Tags: java, c#, c++, windows, native

Going native is extremely good for front end development. Whether its using android vs ionics, c++ vs dotnet/java, the benefits to GUI are significant.

I was wondering if the same had significant effect on back end code. **Is it really that significant** if I rewrite my backend processes in native language?

To be specific I'm looking at TCP related backend services.

Comment: You may want to read this: [C++ performance vs. Java/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/145110/12323248)

Comment: I'd say in general: the closer you get to hardware, the higher the performance-gain of C++ vs Java/C#. If your software is highly abstracted, then there are just other factors that will overweight the performance of native code: development time and so on. TCP is already pretty near to hardware, so I guess .. it's at least worth it to have a look into possible translations. Don't forget that you can have both: native and the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Are you resource-bound?

Specifically, are you strapped for CPU time, memory size or memory bandwidth? (Network-bandwidth is not affected.)

If so, going native might help you, if you have the man-power to write, debug, and maintain the code. Be sure those people won't be needed elsewhere more urgently though.

Still, simply getting a new server, a second one, or even an additional server-farm might be cheaper and get the job done now at much reduced risk.